# Regular Expression (RegEx) to find a particular word in any part of a string but has a character limit

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-like

I'm wanting to use a Regular Expression in SQLs 'LIKE' function to be able to search for strings containing a particular word.

For example, let's say I have a list of folder names (from a laptop) and I want to search for all of the folders that contain the word "Old". Example of results I want:

| Folder Name |
| --- |
| Old Templates |
| old Archives |
| temp - old |

However, when I use:

```
WHERE folder LIKE '%Old%'
```

Obviously, I get the following results:

| Folder Name |
| --- |
| **Old** Templates |
| **old** Archives |
| temp - **old** |
| Har**old** Jenkins |
| Jerry **Old**field |

I just want to use a Regular Expression which searches for the word "Old" at any stage of the string but it searches for only the 3 characters and retrieves the full string.

Just wondering if anyone can help me out - thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you show the desired result?

Comment: BTW, `LIKE` is not regular expressions. Regular expressions are matched with `REGEX` or `RLIKE`.

Comment: Are you asking how to only match whole words, not parts of words, so it won't match `harold`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your response. Ah okay, I was told you can include a RegEx in the LIKE statement if you open with '[a-z]' for example. Basically, the table at the top is my desired results but I'm getting the results of the bottom table. I want to search for the word "old" but not have it return "old" within "Harold" for example.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's what I'm trying to say but I haven't done it very well haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `like` operator has limited functionality, certainly less than regexp. However, what you need can be done by

1. Appending a space to the beginning and end of your search string to ensure it's a different word
2. Doing the same to the target string, so that it will also be matched in the edges:

`where ' '+folder+' ' like '% old %'`

Comment: Eventually, you can use negated character classes instead of spaces in the pattern as a polyfill for regex word boundaries: `like '%[^a-zA-Z]old[^a-zA-Z]%'`. (or `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`)

Comment: @Barmar: the question is tagged tsql.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice that. I usually follow mysql.

Comment: @Barmar: It doesn't matter, but to make you forgive, take a look at my last answer.

Comment: Great, thank you!